# Overview of all the integrated functionality in IAuthRepository in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I was wondering if there is some kind of overview of all the integrated functionally for IAuthRepository (ServiceStack). I know about /register, /auth/credentials. Is there some way to get all the information from the logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [overview of ServiceStack Authentication](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization) is available in the docs.

Specifically ServiceStack's `IAuthRepository` is just the repository used to persist Users which has providers that supports [multiple back-end data stores](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#user-auth-repository). If you wanted to see all information stored about a user you can just inspect the contents of these 2 tables in the data store they're being stored in.

Everything's that needed to know about them can be found by the [IAuthRepository and IUserAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/IAuthRepository.cs) interfaces which defines the API that all Auth Repositories implement and the [UserAuth and UserAuthDetails](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs) Data Models that they all store.

Once a User is Authenticated the information stored about them in the Auth Repository is used to [populate the Users Session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs), which is available in the `AuthUserSession` Type that's [stored in the Cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions), which can be resolved in your Services with:

```
var session = SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
```

Or if you're using an extended [Custom UserSession](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#using-typed-sessions-in-servicestack) you would retrieve the Session into that instead:

```
var session = SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
```

i.e. you should use whatever User Session Type that's registered with the `AuthFeature`:

```
 Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), ...));
```

Comment: What I tried to ask about what the endpoints that are predefined. Like with \register. If I understood your answer correctly, one should implement its own endpoints with the help of the interfaces given.

Comment: @AtleKristiansen Then you're asking about what are the built in Services, not what an AuthRepository is. For Auth there's only the [/auth](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#auth-provider-routes) Service, [Registration](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#authentication) and [Un/Assign Roles Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#assigning-roles-and-permissions). I recommend following the [World Validation](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#world-validation) example for multiple auth + registration examples.